# Yii2 рендер страницы после скачивания файла. Нужна помощь!

Tags: php, yii2, файлы, view, render

Всем привет! Делаю скачивание файла.
Файл лежит по пути: web/register_forms/_тут_язык_/form.xlsx

Вот action на скачивание файла:

```
public function actionDownloadFormFile()
{
    $event = new DownloadFileEvent();

    $event->file_path = Yii::getAlias('@webroot') . '/register_forms/' . User::getLanguage();

    $this->trigger(self::EVENT_DOWNLOAD_FILE, $event);

    return $this->render('empty_list');
}
```

Вот обработчик события:

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    Event::on(self::class, self::EVENT_DOWNLOAD_FILE, function(DownloadFileEvent $event) {

        $file = $event->file_path . '/form.xlsx';

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            Yii::$app->response->sendFile($file);
        }
    });
}
```

В итоге прелоадер постоянно крутится, файл скачивается при этом. Ок. Но не рендерится вьюха.
Помогите пжл разобраться.
Спасибо.

Comment: а если в actionDownloadFormFile() оставить только return $this->render('empty_list'); вьюха рендериться?

Comment: Да, достаточно закомментить вызов триггера. Я так думаю при респонсе возникает конфликт между отправкой файла и рендером. То есть по сути что одно что второе это респонс.

Comment: ну да проблема в событии, а почему Вы просто через $app->sendFile не отдаёте?

Comment: Как по-вашему это работает? Что значит файл скачивается? А это значит что файл передаётся в теле ответа (вы же знаете про HTTP?). А вьюха куда, как вы думаете, рендерится? В тело ответа! Поэтому вы не можете одновременно отправлять в ответе файл и html страницы.

Answer (score 1):

В экшне на скачивание файла вы должны либо отдать файл, либо (если файл не найден) ответить ошибкой 404. Браузеры при получении ответа с файлом понимают, что это не страница (другой content-type) и просто скачивают файл не перезагружая текущую страницу. Если вам нужно перенаправить пользователя на какую-то страницу после загрузки файла, вы можете сделать это на клиенте с помощью js.

Comment: В том то и вопрос, как поймать момент завершения скачивания в клиентском скрипте.

Comment: @OlegBolden конкретно тут был вопрос почему не отрабатывает `$this->render('empty_list');` после `Yii::$app->response->sendFile($file);`.  Ответ на ваш вопрос можете поискать тут на сайте. Если не найдёте, задайте, вам ответят.